# On Click of Lightning:Datatable ,insert email template in lightning-input-rich-text

Tags: lightning-web-components, email-template, onclick

I am trying to replicate email template selection using LWC. Here is screenshot of what I am bulding sequence 1,2,3,4. First I am getting the orgwide email adress and that is shown in a combobox as a dropdown(1), then user will select the template folder again a comboxbox(2) based on selected folder Id  the email template will be shown in Datatable(3), now the Name column must be like a 'link' and on 'Name' click, the rich text area(4) must be populated with email template. **Point 3 and 4 is not done**.   Can someone help me with some coding help or advice.

[image]

````
<template>
    <div>
    <lightning-combobox
            name="Sender"
            label="Sender"
            value= ""
            placeholder="Choose Sender"
            options={senders}
            onchange={handleChangedSender}
            required>
    </lightning-combobox>
</div>
<div>
    <lightning-combobox
            name="TemplateFolders"
            label="Template Folders"
            value= {folderValue}
            placeholder="Select Folder"
            options={FolderList}
            onchange={handleChangeFolder}
            required>
    </lightning-combobox>
</div>
<div style="height: 300px;">
    <lightning-datatable
            key-field="Id"
            data={match}
            columns={columns}
            hide-checkbox-column="true">
    </lightning-datatable>
</div>
<div>
<lightning-input-rich-text
        value={richTextValue}
        onchange={handleChangeRichInput}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
</div>
</template>


import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import TemplateFolders from "@salesforce/apex/FolderEmailTemplateClass.ReturnFolderList";
import TemplateList from "@salesforce/apex/FolderEmailTemplateClass.ReturnTemplateList";
import SenderList from "@salesforce/apex/FolderEmailTemplateClass.ReturnSenderList";
const columns = [
{
    label: 'Name', 
    fieldName: 'Name', 
    sortable: true
},
{   
    label: 'Description', 
    fieldName: 'Description' 
}
];
export default class EmailCmp extends LightningElement {
folderValue='';
senderValue='';
columns = columns;
@track FolderList;
@wire(TemplateFolders, {})
getTemplateFolders({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        try {
            let options = [];
            for (var key in data) {
                // Here key will have index of list of records starting from 0,1,2,....
                options.push({ label: data[key].Name, value: data[key].Id  });
            }
            this.FolderList = options;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('check error here', error);
        }
    } else if (error) {
        console.error('check error here', error);
    }
}
match = [];
@wire(TemplateList, {folderId: '$folderValue'})
getEmailTemplates({data, error}){
    if(data){
        console.log('email temp = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        let options = [];
        data.forEach(element => {
            let elt = {};
            elt.Name = element.Name ;
            elt.Description =  element.Description ;
            options.push(elt);
        });
        this.match = options;

    }else if(error){
        console.log('error >>> data.... '+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}

senders=[];
@wire(SenderList, {})
getSender({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        try {
            let options = [];
            for (var key in data) {
                // Here key will have index of list of records starting from 0,1,2,....
                options.push({label: data[key].Address, value: data[key].DisplayName});
            }
            this.senders = options;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('check error here', error);
        }
    } else if (error) {
        console.error('check error here', error);
    }
}

handleChangeFolder(event) {
    console.log('log = '+ event.detail.value);
    this.folderValue=event.detail.value;
}

handleChangeRichInput(event) {
    this.richTextValue = event.target.value;
}
handleChangedSender(event){
    this.senderValue=event.detail.value;
}
} ```
````